# When using Trac and SVN together, how will I know that a file is committed to solve a certain ticket?

Tags: file, svn, commit, trac

For example, a file is modified to do an enhance ticket, what I want to do is associated the committed file to the ticket. When using Trac and SVN together, how will I know that a file is committed to solve a certain ticket? Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated on the [`TracWiki`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracAndVersioning), the intended workflow is:

> 1. A Trac user begins work on a ticket
> 2. They obtain code from the version control system
> 3. After the work is completed they perform a commit of their
>      modifications to the version control
>      repository
> 4. The user inserts the Trac ticket number into the commit message as a
>      [`TracLink`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks)
> 5. Trac can now display the change set for the ticket

Where the TracLink is something like `#1` or `ticket:1` or even `comment:1:ticket:2` when referring to a ticket.

---

If you miss creating the link when the commit is made, you can still create one in the ticket comments themselves using [`TracLinks`](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks) such as: `r2`, `r1:3`, `[1:3]`, `log:@1:3`, etc.

Comment: And the basic link could be added via svn:bugtraq properties, at least for clients that support it.

Comment: Additionaly, you can setup a post-commit script to automatically push tickets to testing (or whatever workflow you use)

Comment: I'm fairly sure the Trac post-commit hook must be enabled (as retractile mentioned), and it is not by default in aTrac installation.

Answer (score 2):

you can link to the revision when closing ticket: `r253`, e.g.
and you can link to the ticket in commit message: `#7525`, e.g.

other than that, I doubt that anything can be done.

Obviously you could parse log message with on-commit hook and make a notification of sorts re tickets of interest, but you'd need to have access to the server I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the Trac post-commit hook useful.  It allows you to close tickets using your commit log messages.  See [the script here](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook).